# Visual Studio Create Declaration / Definition remove space before star/ampersand for the pointer/reference type parameters

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, visual-studio-2017, autoformatting

There is an option in MSVS to `Create Declaration / Definition` for a function. Example:

Consider you have written your function declaration in `foo.h` as follows:

```
int foo(char* cstr, vector<int>& v);
```

You press `Alt+Enter`, select `Create Declaration / Definition` and the following definition appears in `foo.cpp`:

```
void foo(char * cstr, vector<int> & v)
{
    return 0;
}
```

But here's the problem: the spaces around `*` and `&` symbols are not preserved.

I tried looking for an option in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting` but haven't found anything which affects this case.

Is it possible to configure how `Create Declaration / Definition` generates spaces around `*` and `&`? How?